# Count records for each age range

Tags: mysql, select, subquery

I have a mysql table

## TABLE name test

```
Id INT PRIMARY KEY
Lahir Date
Gender CHAR(1)
Nama Varchar(100)
id_desa CHAR(4)
```

How can I get report like this?

```
id_desa 0-10 11-20 21-30 31-40 41-50
10B      1      2     0    1     8
10C      2      4     7    1     0.
```

Comment: What is `0-10,11-20......`?? Provide some sample table data.

Comment: What have you done so far?

Comment: This should work in MySQL as well: http://stackoverflow.com/a/26276492/330315

Answer (score 0):

try

```
select
     id_desa,
     sum(case when FLOOR(DATEDIFF(Lahir,NOW())/365) between 0 and 10 then 1 else 0 end) as '0-10',
     sum(case when FLOOR(DATEDIFF(Lahir,NOW())/365) between 11 and 20 then 1 else 0 end) as '11-20',
     sum(case when FLOOR(DATEDIFF(Lahir,NOW())/365) between 21 and 30 then 1 else 0 end) as '21-30',
     sum(case when FLOOR(DATEDIFF(Lahir,NOW())/365) between 31 and 40 then 1 else 0 end) as '31-40',
     sum(case when FLOOR(DATEDIFF(Lahir,NOW())/365) between 41 and 50 then 1 else 0 end) as '41-50'
    from tbl
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try to use this query.
I assume that the table name is name_test.

```
SELECT id_desa,
    (SELECT Count(*) FROM name_test WHERE DATE_FORMAT(FROM_DAYS(DATEDIFF(Now(),Lahir)), "%y")+0 BETWEEN 0 AND 10) as "0-10",     
    (SELECT Count(*) FROM name_test WHERE DATE_FORMAT(FROM_DAYS(DATEDIFF(Now(),Lahir)), "%y")+0 BETWEEN 11 AND 20) as "11-20",     
    (SELECT Count(*) FROM name_test WHERE DATE_FORMAT(FROM_DAYS(DATEDIFF(Now(),Lahir)), "%y")+0 BETWEEN 21 AND 30) as "21-30", 
    (SELECT Count(*) FROM name_test WHERE DATE_FORMAT(FROM_DAYS(DATEDIFF(Now(),Lahir)), "%y")+0 BETWEEN 31 AND 40) as "31-40", 
    (SELECT Count(*) FROM name_test WHERE DATE_FORMAT(FROM_DAYS(DATEDIFF(Now(),Lahir)), "%y")+0 BETWEEN 41 AND 50) as "41-50"
FROM name_test
```

Comment: Ah yes the closing bracket is missing. Thanks. Fixed now.

Answer (score 0):

MySQL has a very nice function called TIMESTAMPDIFF

```
SELECT
    id_desa,
    SUM(TIMESTAMPDIFF(YEAR, Lahir, CURRENT_DATE) BETWEEN 0 AND 10) `0-10`,
    SUM(TIMESTAMPDIFF(YEAR, Lahir, CURRENT_DATE) BETWEEN 11 AND 20) `11-20`,
    SUM(TIMESTAMPDIFF(YEAR, Lahir, CURRENT_DATE) BETWEEN 21 AND 30) `21-30`,
    SUM(TIMESTAMPDIFF(YEAR, Lahir, CURRENT_DATE) BETWEEN 31 AND 40) `31-40`,
    SUM(TIMESTAMPDIFF(YEAR, Lahir, CURRENT_DATE) BETWEEN 41 AND 50) `41-50`,
    SUM(TIMESTAMPDIFF(YEAR, Lahir, CURRENT_DATE) > 50) `50+`
FROM tablename
GROUP BY id_desa
```

Comment: yeah THanks so much, yes i get it output like your Query, thanks thanks so much :-D

Comment: If this is the correct answer, then mark it that way. Other people might think the problem isn't solved yet.

Comment: the problem has been completed with the queries you write